# Is it possible to eliminate the unit rules in this?

Tags: context-free, chomsky-hierarchy

```
S -> aA | bC | CC | a | b | C
A -> B
B -> S
C -> A | S
```

It looks like its going to loop so it would be endless replacing the unit rule....

Comment: We prefer that you do research to try to answer your own question, before asking. Doing a websearch on "context-free grammar eliminate unit rules" turns up resources that describe how to eliminate unit rules, including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#UNIT:_Eliminate_unit_rules.  If your question is answered in standard resources (e.g., Wikipedia) and can be found through websearch, you probably haven't done enough research before asking here -- there's little point in us repeating information that's already readily available in standard sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove A,B,C and replace all instances of them in the rule S, with S.

Comment: So what will happen to the C in S? Will it just disappear?

Comment: S --> aS | bS | a | b

Comment: S -> aA | bC | CC
 A -> B
 B -> S | epsilon
 C -> A | S

Comment: Also the CFG you provided at the top can terminate. There are just redundant rules.

Comment: This was the original...

Comment: I have applied in removing the epsilon rules, which resulted it the one i posted

Comment: The original cfg also can terminate.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! This is a uni assignment btw. The lecturers and supervisors did not mention anything about terminating non terminals. What you explained makes so much sense. Do you think explaining it to them the answer would give me the same mark as writing all the redundant values? lol

Comment: I'm not certain what the specific question is. Hopefully you understand CFGs a bit better now. Please note Yuval's answer as well about how every CFG can be transformed into CNF

Comment: Im sorry but last question. Since B is nullable, does that mean all of the non terminals including S is nullable?

Comment: Those are nullable. But not for the sole reason that B is nullable, but because A =>* B and C =>* B

Answer (score 1):

You can always eliminate unit rules. In fact, every context-free grammar can be massaged to one in [Chomsky normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form), and there are several algorithms doing that. Their treatment of unit rules is more subtle than what you suggest.